# How can I prevent system from suspending/locking (Python/C/Bash)

Tags: python, c, linux, ubuntu

How can I prevent system (while my application is open) from suspending ? (Linux - Ubuntu 10.04) If it is not possible only by python, maybe some Bash, C command/libraries ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python

```
import dbus
_session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()

_dbus_screensaver = _session_bus.get_object('org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver','/ScreenSaver')

simulate_activity = _dbus_screensaver.get_dbus_method('SimulateUserActivity','org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver')

simulate_activity()
```

In bash:

```
qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver.SimulateUserActivity
```

Comment: & do this in an infinite loop, with some delay. :)

Comment: +1, for I did not know that there is a dedicated way to do it. I was going to suggest simulate key strokes / mouse-movements using `xte`

Comment: Wow - super, I already found that dbus (by previous answer) and what it is capable of, but I wouldn't find out how to use it properly in such short amount of time - thanks :)

Comment: Could you please update your answer? I tried to use this code on Ubuntu 13.04 and **DIDN'T WORKED**.

Comment: use qdbus and find out if the function is still there. If it is report a bug, if not... can't help.

Comment: @Zignd. Here it is how I am doing it right now:  Invoked via python bash script with: gnome-screensaver-command -p

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in C, start here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/GnomePowerManagerInactiveSleep

Answer (score 0):

You can add a script to `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` returning an error when your application is running

```
#! /bin/sh

ps -e -o comm | grep -q application
if test $? -eq 0; then
    exit 1
fi
```

When your `application` is found in the list of processes and the script exits with an error (`1`) the suspend is aborted. Otherwise it returns `0` and the suspend continues.

Of course, you can use any other test for your application.